# How to wrap each pair in the div inside {{#each}} loop

Tags: ember.js

Question is how to wrap every two subsequent items inside {{#each}} loop in a div to get this layout

```
<ul>
  <div>
    <li>first item</li>
    <li> second item</li>
  </div>
  <div>
    <li>third item</li>
    <li> fourth item</li>
  </div>
  // etc...
</ul>
```

for that model

```
[
  {id: 1, name: 'first item'},
  {id: 2, name: 'second item'},
  {id: 3, name: 'third item'},
  {id: 4, name: 'fourth item'},
  // etc...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a straight up way to do this using the `{{#each}}` helper.

Here's what I would do...

### 1.

Write a custom template helper ( starting with [{{#each}}](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.11.1/packages/ember-htmlbars/lib/helpers/each.js#L159) )

### 2. Re-model the Array

```
 model: function() {
      var arr = [
            {id: 1, name: 'first item'},
            {id: 2, name: 'second item'},
            {id: 3, name: 'third item'},
            {id: 4, name: 'fourth item'},
            // etc...
      ];
      // splits array in pairs of 2
      return _.chunk(arr, 2); 
 }
```

[_.chunk](https://lodash.com/docs#chunk) is a lodash helper but you can easily roll your own implementation.

#### Template:

```
 <ul>
 {{#each model as |pair|}}
      <li>{{pair.firstObject}}</li>
      <li>{{pair.lastObjectObject}}</li>
 {{/each}
 </ul>
```

`.firstObject` and `.lastObject` are `Ember.Array` helpers.
If you have `EXTEND_PROTOTYPES` disabled you can do the following instead:

```
 <ul>
 {{#each model as |pair|}}
      {{#each pair as |item|}}
           <li>{{item}}</li>
      {{/each}
 {{/each}
 </ul>
```

Comment: looks like re-model data is the only way